# как запустить python-скрипт в js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, node.js

Есть основной файл src/App.js. Структура файла следующая:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
... // импорты всякие
class Testo extends Component {
  state ={
  ... // стейты
  }
  ... // тут всякие функции и прочее
    render() {
      return (
      ... // тут разметка страницы
      )
    }
}
```

Есть сторонний модуль python-shell на https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell
с примерами интеграции и запуска через него python-скрипта.
**Вопрос: КАК** мне написать код для запуска python-скрипта, чтобы он вернул значение после выполнения и **самое главное ГДЕ** мне вставить этот код чтобы он выполнился, например, по нажатию кнопки?
Я уже как только не пробовал - всё время какие-то ошибки выходят по типа:
TypeError: PythonShell is not a constructor
или
TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function.

Comment: В среде браузера пайтон скрипт запустить нельзя. Оберниет его на бэке в апишку и вызывайте с фронта. Или, если ваш питон-код не связан с бэком, а работает с данными, перепишите его на javaScript

Comment: Похожий ответ я уже видел на англоязычной версии сайта. У бэкенд на Django REST. Есть ли какой-то вариант как можно такой скрипт превратить в API? Сам скрипт посылает ПОСТ-запрос, получает данные и парсит их. "если ваш питон-код не связан с бэком, а работает с данными, перепишите его на javaScript" - не вариант. Мой фронт на https, а запрос отправляется на http, и он блокируется корс-полиси браузера.

Comment: Чем, по вашему, REST отличается от API? Я не знаю, что там у вас за бэк у сайта, но можно запрос отправлять на бэк по https, бэк будет дергать питон-скрипт по удобному для него адресу, передавать данные, получать ответ и возвращать клиенту.